# Formulario sencillo Ruby on Rails subida de un archivo input de tipo file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Resulta que estoy intentando hacer un formulario cuya única acción es pedirle al usuario que elija un archivo de su computador mediante un
 `<input type="file" class="form-control-file"
id="exampleFormControlFile1">`

El problema es que no encuentro solución para poder configurar correctamente el `<form></form>`

Bueno, este seria el fragmento de código, que no logro programar:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Selecciones su Cv</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
</form>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

La pregunta es, ¿cómo hago que el botón logre enviar el archivo?

La verdad tengo todo resuelto con AWS, se como configurarlo para recibir los curriculum a este servidor.

La verdad necesito ayuda con el `form` para que funcione via POST_ y que me digan si es necesario hacer cambios en el controlador o el modelo.

Gracias, si necesitan mas código se los envío.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios puntos que debes actualizar en tu forma:

- Necesitas especificar la acción, el método y la codificación de la forma antes de ser enviada (esto se logra con los atributos `action`, `method` y `enctype`).
- Debes dar nombre al campo que estás enviando.
- El botón de `submit` debe estar **dentro** de la forma.
- Se debe agregar el *token de autenticidad*.

Considerando lo anterior, así se vería el código:

```
<form action="<%= posts_path %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Selecciones su Cv</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y en tu controlador podrás tener acceso al archivo por medio del objeto `params` junto con el nombre asignado al `input`; por ejemplo:

```
file = params[:exampleFormControlFile1]
```

Claro que, a mi criterio, la mejor opción sería utilizar los *helpers* que proporciona *Rails* para generar formas; en este caso `form_tag` sería adecuado, por ejemplo:

```
<%= form_tag(post_path, multipart: true) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:exampleFormControlFile1 "Seleccione su CV") %>
    <%= file_field_tag(:exampleFormControlFile1, class: "form-control-file") %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag("Enviar", class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
```

Al utilizar `posts_path` se asume que tienes correctamente configuradas tus rutas en *config/routes.rb* y que la acción que deseas llamar an tu controlador es `create` (la cual sería la adecuada para **crear** un nuevo registro).

Comment: Tengo mi controller que se llama post_controller y dentro del metodo new puse el objeto params que me diste.
Para el action no me quedo muy claro pero lo tengo asi; action="/post_controller" (Es el nombre de mi controller).

Si no es asi podrias darme un ejemplo? 

Grande @Gerry!!

Comment: Lo otro Garry, no tengo idea como poner la ruta en routes, tengo esto. post "posts" => "posts#new"

Comment: @UpsetGrade He actualizado la respuesta para incluir la ruta adecuada, espero te ayude.

Comment: Al parecer no se asume nada aun en el archivo routes, ya que tengo el siguiente mensaje de error uninitialized constant PostsController.

Que crees que deberia hacer?, en algunos foros recomiendan agregar una ruta como esta 
post "posts" => "posts#new"

Pero tampoco me da resultado.

Comment: @UpsetGrade La configuración de _routes/config.rb_ la debes llevar a cabo tu, para este caso específico podrías utilizar `post '/posts:', to: 'posts#create'`; con respecto al error que te sale, necesitas haber creado el controlador correspondiente, i.e. `PostsController`, ¿ya lo creaste? Dentro de ese controlador debes definir la acción `create` que se encargue de recibir y procesar el _request_.

Comment: @Garry de todas maneras cambie mi antiguo PostController por PostsController, pero sigo teniendo el mismo error...Te cuento, en mi PostsController tengo el método new que contiene el objeto params que me recomendaste, y el método create que contiene la lógica para guardar y crear el posts....No se que podría estar mal, o algún detalle faltante

error: No route matches [POST] "/posts"

Comment: @UpsetGrade ¿Podrías abrir otra pregunta con el error que te muestra y el código de tu controlador y archivo _routes.rb_? No lo agregues a esta pregunta pues perderá el sentido la respuesta actual (por cierto, si el _request_ ya funciona, no olvides aceptar la respuesta dando clic a la paloma; el otro error lo resolveremos por separado); recuerda que SO funciona mejor dejando un problema por pregunta.

Comment: Garry ya abrí otra pregunta, aquí te dejo el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233628/no-route-matches-post-rails-form-tag