# No route matches [POST] "/" Rails Form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Resulta que estoy construyendo un form donde se puede seleccionar un archivo. El problema es que al intentar construirlo me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/"
```

Enseguida mostrare el contenido de mi controller y mi archivo de rutas más el contenido que conforma el form_tag.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitas mas info, no tengas problema en pedírmelo.

Comment: el path del form no es el correcto, mira que estas apuntando a root pero la ruta es /posts

Comment: No publiques tu código con imagenes. Es mas fácil para el que intenta responder, si copias y pegas el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que muestras se debe a que estás utilizando `root_path` para el envío de tu forma, pero deberías utilizar `posts_path` para que tu forma se envíe a la acción `create` de tu controlador `PostsController`; ejemplo:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, multipart: true) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Para que el *helper* `posts_path` esté disponible, debes actualizar tus rutas (i.e. *config/routes.rb*) agregando `resources :posts` en lugar de `post '/posts', to: 'posts#create'.

Lo anterior soluciona el error, pero tu forma seguirá sin funcionar ya que el contenido de la acción `create` no procesa la información que recibes de la forma (lo estás haciendo en `new`, lo cual es incorrecto). Siguiendo los estándares de Rails (y de *REST*), `new` solo responde con el verbo `GET`, mientras que `create` responde a `POST`. Por lo tanto, ajusta el controlador `PostsController` para que refleje lo anterior; por ejemplo:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    file = params[:exampleFormControlFile1]
    # código para guardar/procesar el archivo
  end
end
```

Es importante aclarar que el código que tienes actualmente en `create` no funcionará debido a que `post_params` no contiene la información de la forma, pero funcionará si ajustas ese método (y asumiendo que has configurado tu modelo `Post` adecuadamente); de hecho ese código es más cercano a lo que deberías poner en tu aplicación que, respetando el código de tu forma, podría ser algo así<sup>1</sup>:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.permit(:exampleFormControlFile1)
  end
end
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Se asume que la forma se encuentra en el archivo *new.html.erb*, que sería lo correcto siguiendo los estándares de Rails.</sup>

Comment: Ya arregle el path, luego arregle el contenido del postscontroller pero arroja el siguiente error undefined local variable or method `post_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd8019ef148>:0x007fd806fb87f0>
Did you mean?  font_path
               root_path

Comment: @UpsetGrade Debe ser `posts_path`, pero pusiste `post_path`.

Comment: Garry con ninguna de las dos funciona, creo que no esta reconociendo el posts_path por alguna razón.¿Qué podría ser?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `posts_path'   ese es el error final

Comment: @UpsetGrade Hacía falta una actualización en tus rutas, por favor mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Garry al intentar eso me arroja el siguiente error -   ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in PostsController#create  -  unknown attribute 'exampleFormControlFile1' for Post.
y apunta a la siguiente linea de codigo en el metodo create

 @post = Post.new(post_params)

Comment: @UpsetGrade El error se debe a que tu modelo `Post` no tiene un atributo (i.e. columna) con el nombre `exampleFormControlFile1`; cambia el nombre en la forma para que corresponda con el de tu modelo.

Comment: Garry enseñanos los pasos para hacerlo

Comment: @UpsetGrade Solo cambia el nombre por el del atributo en tu modelo donde quieres guardar la referencia al archivo. Si quieres más detalle, te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta con el código de tu modelo y la migración relacionada. Mientras tanto, no olvides marcar como aceptada esta respuesta (dando clic a la paloma) si resolvió el error original (i.e. el que muestras en el título).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89090/discussion-between-upset-grade-and-gerry).

Comment: @Garry https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234279/unknown-action-the-action-index-could-not-be-found-for-postscontroller-rails